# Modify Model Before Showing

Tags: angularjs

I am designing an Angular app (my first one) and so far everything has been going relatively simple, however I have run into a problem. In my application, the user creates a list of text items, each item has some formatting attached to it. This creates a list in my controller of the items.

```
items = [{"text":"Example","bold":true},{"text":"More..."}...]
```

This all works perfectly, however I need to give this information back to the user and need to modify the object slightly before it goes back onto the page.

I can do something like this:

```
<span>{{cntrl.items}}</span>
```

But this doesn't let me modify the data before it shows up in the model.

Right now I am using ng-change to call a function which stores the generated string in a variable:

```
<span>{{cntrl.output}}</span>
```

This works, except I need to put an ng-change on everything to get live outputs. My processing work is *not* resource intensive and can run on every user interaction.

How can I make this happen whenever the `items` variable in my controller is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you want to modify your models before display it. It is quite tricky because if you need some complex modification it will sure change the value that user input.

So it will be better if you make 2 seperate models. Line `input` and `output` then user a function to parse the output from the input.

You can do something like this. (hit `Run code Snippet` )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    
      angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.userInput = '';
        $scope.userOutput = function(){
          return myService.parser($scope.userInput)
        };
      })
      .service('myService', function(){
        return {
          parser: function(input){
            return input ? input+'---parsed' : 'User has not input anything...';
          }
        }
      });
 
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="userInput" placeholder="input stuff here...">
    <div>{{userOutput()}}</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is a [**plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AnXu9jxNMhnYsg1iCzbT?p=preview) (in case loading angular on SO got some problem)

**EDIT** : update code to make it look better.